# In JUnit-5, How do I mock a static method that returns void? Can we use import org.mockito.MockedStatic?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, powermock, powermockito

I have a few 3rd parties static util methods in my project, some of them just pass or throw an exception. There are a lot of examples out there on how to mock a static method using PowerMock but Junit5 doesn't support PowerMock, which has a return type other than void. But how can I mock a static method that returns void to just "doNothing()"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mock it. From your minimal description, you could replace the usage sites with `Consumer` and provide a mock of that. (You can even initialize the fields with method references to the static methods and just have setter methods to override them.)

However, the fact that the class under test calls these static methods is *usually* just an implementation detail that the test shouldn't care about, only checking observable behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but for my test to run I have to call that static void Util method. In Junit-5, I didn't see a way to mock a static void method.

Answer (score 0):

Build a wrapper class on it, call the wrapper method,  and you can have a different wrapper in your test if you can do behavior differently or have the wrapper to call a class/method can be mocked ,

Comment: Will you please share an example for the same?